# The link interface of target <target> contains: <dependency> but the target was not found

Tags: c++, cmake

Theres a lib having a Qt dependecy in its public link interface. When the client calls find_package it errors :

```
CMake Error at <path>/albert-targets.cmake:47 (set_target_properties):
  The link interface of target "albert::albert" contains:

    Qt6::Concurrent

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  <path>/albert-config.cmake:30 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

Do I have to `find_dependency` for public link interface libraries in a CMake config? If I do a `find_dependency` in the config file, why would I have to put the libraries in the public link interface at all? Is the public link interface redundant? At least it does not make any difference for the client if the dependency is public or private if I call find dependency.

Comment: Looks like you just need to `find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Concurrent)` before you `find_package(whatever)`. As a rationale behind having it in public link interface: maybe author prefers that your project fails to configure on cmake step instead of fail to link after compilation.

Comment: "Do I have to `find_dependency` for public link interface libraries in a CMake config?" - Yes, the config file for `albert` package needs to have the call `find_dependency` for QT. "If I do a `find_package` in the config file" - Config files prefer to call `find_dependency` instead of `find_package`. Or do you mean that you call `find_package` from the `CMakeLists.txt` script in the `albert` project?

Comment: I mean to write `find_dependency`. Well if I have to find it anyway I dont get the purpose of the public link interface.

Comment: The purpose of public linkage is to remember linkage with `Qt6::Concurrent` **target**. The purpose of the `find_package` in the `CMakeLists.txt` to fill properties of that target on the **build** machine. The purpose of `find_dependency` in the config file is to provide that target on the **target** machine, where your library's project could be used. So, every command is responsible for the specific effects.